# Linearly disjoint family of fields $\{L_i \}_{i=1}^n$ over $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-extensions

Suppose that $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a number field.

$(*)$ Let $L_1,\dots,L_n/K$ be a finite family of finite Galois extensions such that $L_i\cap L_j = K$ for all $i,j$.

Is this enough to conclude that $L_1,\dots,L_n$ are linearly disjoint over $K$, i.e.
$$ L_j\cap L_1\dots L_{j-1}=K \quad\text{for all }j=1,\dots,n? \tag{**} $$
Clearly, the $(**)$ implies $(*)$. But I believe $(*)$ implies $(**)$ is false in general. Does anyone have a counterexample that they can share with me?

Comment: I don't think so - I believe the following is a counterexample. Note that two quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ have nontrivial intersection if and only if they are equal. However, consider the extensions $L_{1} = \mathbb{Q}(i), L_{2} = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}), L_{3} = \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity. Then $L_{i} \cap L_{j} = \mathbb{Q}$ for each $i, j$, but $L_{3} \cap L_{1}L_{2} = L_{3}$, since $\omega$ is contained in $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{3})$.

Comment: Nice example. Thanks for helping me again!

Comment: Happy to do it, and glad it was helpful!

Comment: For future readers, here is a little intuition I made up for myself. Let $L_1,L_2,L_3/\mathbb{Q}$ satisfy the pairwise intersection conditions, then $\operatorname{Gal}(L_1L_2/\mathbb{Q}) = \operatorname{Gal}(L_1/\mathbb{Q})\times \operatorname{Gal}(L_2/\mathbb{Q}) =: G_1\times G_2$. If neither $G_1$ nor $G_2$ are simple, then $L_1L_2$ has a subfield contained in neither $L_1$ nor $L_2$. This is where pairwise intersection breaks down.

Comment: It is better to post answers as answers, not as comments.